# Activity receive onResume event before another disappear

Tags: java, android

I am programming an app with the use of OpenGL and SurfaceView.
I need to detect when an activity finishes and I return to my activity.
I need it because I don't want to respond to touch and key events until my activity is shown.

Now I detect it with onResume, but onResume is called before the finishing activity disappears.
I need to enable these events when my activity is being shown (mostly because of onBackPressed).

Anyone with a solution?

EDIT:
find some information about it, so when the activity is doing something in its onStop/onDestroy method, then it is after onResume of my activity was called -> my problem
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#CoordinatingActivities

EDIT2:
onStop and onDestroy are called when activity is not showing

EDIT3: found that it is caused because of new thread doing work in onPause, still no solution

Comment: Have you tried use onPostResume() ？

Comment: no I will try it and post result

Comment: onPostResume is called immediately after onResume() method so it changes nothing for me

Comment: What about onStop() in the Activity that is closing?  It should be not visible (and the other one visible) when this is called.

Comment: i have tested it know with my own closing activity, and it only happens when onPause uses new Thread to do something, because then onPause execution is finished and onResume of my activity called even when the finishing activity is still displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird because onResume should be called when your activity is visible.
You could activate your touch controls with a small delay using a handler.

Comment: I will try it, but it tooks different time to exit every time, i have to choose longest delay and that will sometimes cause not to interact with user :)

Comment: found this as solution, because other methods wont work